# firebase/flutter: Multiple where queries

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with one array that holds userId's.

I know I only have 2 users in the incoming array. I tried the following snip but I am getting an error

```
  Future getChat({required List<String> userIdsArr}) async {
    print('userIdsArr[0]:  ${userIdsArr[0]}');
    print('userIdsArr[1]:  ${userIdsArr[1]}');

    var data = await chat.where(
        'User ids', 'array-contains-any', ['firebase', 'react']).snapshots();

    print(data);
  }
```

error I am getting here is

```
Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 3 found.
lib/…/cloud/firebase_cloud_storage.dart:44
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    var data = await chat.where(
                               ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for building a query in Flutter is slightly different. If your `chat` is a query or collection reference, the `array-contains-any` would be:

```
chat.where('User ids', arrayContainsAny: ['firebase', 'react'])
```

Also see the [Dart/Flutter code sample for `array-contains-any`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_9) in the documentation.